# Indirect proof, Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$ then $d(x_n , y_n) \to d(x,y)$ is easy if showing it directly:

$$ |d(x,y) - d(x_n, y_n) | \le |d(x,x_n) + d(y,y_n)| \le \varepsilon$$

I am now trying to show it indirectly (by contradiction).

My try: Assume $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$ but $d(x_n, y_n ) \not\to d(x,y)$. Since $\mathbb R$ is complete and $d(x_n, y_n)$ is Cauchy it follows $d(x_n, y_n)$ converges. Therefore without loss of generality assume $d(x_n, y_n) \to L < d(x,y)$.

$|d(x,x_n) + d(y,y_n) | = |d(x_n,x) + d(x_n,y_n) - d(y_n,x_n) + d(y_n, y)| \ge$

$ |d(x,y_n) + d(y_n,y) - d(y_n, x_n)| \ge |d(x,y) - d(x_n,y_n)| = |L+\varepsilon - d(x_n,y_n)|$

$ > 0$ since $L-d(x_n,y_n) > \varepsilon' > 0$ for $n >$ some $n \in \mathbb N$.

Is this valid proof? It is remark in lecture notes. It says try to show it by direct and then by indirect proof. I did direct proof. I don't know what indirect proof is I thought it is proof by contradiction. I don't have to do this but I was curious so I tried. But I can't do it!

Comment: *I am now trying to show it indirectly (by contradiction)*... Why?

Comment: If your conclusion is $|d(x,x_n)+d(y,y_n)|\gt0$, how does that prove $d(x_n,y_n)\to d(x,y)$?

Comment: @Did For practice.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then either $d(x,x_n)>0$ or $d(y_n,y)>0$ therefore contradiction because both assumed to converge to zero.

Comment: $d(x,x_n)\gt0$ does not contradict $d(x,x_n)\to0$ any more than $1/n\gt0$ contradicts $1/n\to0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is it now contradicting? I changed it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe I am wrong and "indirect proof" $\neq$ "proof by contradiction"?

Comment: I think "indirect proof" does mean "proof by contradiction", but I still don't see where you have reached a contradiction. Proving every term in a sequence is positive does not contradict the limit of the sequence being zero.

Comment: Practice of what?

Comment: @Did I practicing proofs.